# ReactJS onAnimationEnd doesn't execute during Tests

Tags: reactjs

I have a control of which I want to be aware of it's animation start and end. I ended up coding something similar to what is below but during my test (Mocha + Phantom + Karma) the onAnimationEnd event doesn't seem to fire.

The start is easy as it happens on click but the end is my current issue. I've added an example below. If anyone can see what the issue is I'd love to know!

P.S. - Sorry for not having the code in a snippet, I didn't know of any snippet generator that handled test cases.

CSS

```
@keyframes exampleAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

.testObject {
    &.animate {
        animation-name: exampleAnimation;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

TypeScript

```
import React = require("react");

export interface ITestControlProps {
    /**
     * Called when the element is clicked
     */
    onClick?: () => void;

    /**
     * Called when the animation is complete
     */
    onAnimationComplete?: () => void;
}
export interface ITestControlState {
    /**
     * if the element has been clicked
     */
    isClicked: boolean;
}

export class TestControl extends React.Component<ITestControlProps, ITestControlState> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isClicked: false
    };
  }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        let buttonClassName = "testObject ";

        if (this.state.isClicked) {
            buttonClassName += " animate";
        }

        return (
            <button
                className = {buttonClassName}
                onClick = {this.onClick.bind(this)}
                onAnimationEnd = {this.onAnimationComplete.bind(this)}
                >
                Click me!
            </button>
        );
    }

    /**
     * When the button is clicked
     * @param evt: The event that caused this method to be called.  Can be a click or a button press.
     */
    private onClick(evt: UIEvent) {
        this.setState((prevState: ITestControlState) => {
            prevState.isClicked = !prevState.isClicked;
            return prevState;
        });

        if (this.props.onClick != null) {
            this.props.onClick();
        }

        console.log("On click fired");
    }

    /**
     * When the pulse animation is complete
     */
    private onAnimationComplete(): void {
        if (this.props.onAnimationComplete != null) {
            this.props.onAnimationComplete();
        }
        console.log("onAnimationComplete fired");
    }
}
```

TypeScript - Test

```
import chai = require("chai");
import React = require("react");

// Control
import {TestControl} from "planner/controls/PresentationalControls";

const expect = chai.expect;
const TestUtils = React["addons"].TestUtils;

describe("TestControl Control Unit Test", () => {

    let renderedComponent: TestControl;

    describe("TestControl default render", () => {

        it ("Animation Complete Success", (done: MochaDone) => {
            let animationCompleteFunc = () => {
                done();
            };

            renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
                <TestControl
                    onAnimationComplete = {animationCompleteFunc}>
                </TestControl>
            );

            expect(renderedComponent).to.not.be.undefined;

            var button = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(renderedComponent, "button")[0];

            TestUtils.Simulate.click(button);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note, I thought it maybe something to do with the virtual dom (who knows at this point) so I also used ReactDom to render it in the body of the document and I still don't get the event.

Answer (score 0):

This requires two changes. First at the top of the Control file you need to add

```
///<amd-dependency path="./PulseButton.css" />
```

Second TestUtils doesn't actually fire the events from the DOM. This means that though your code will work in a browser, you can't use TestUtils to write these tests.

Instead, you would have to actually mount the component to the document in phantom to get the events to fire correctly.